# Board in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

Can we render the chess board in the Android SE app? It would be valuable and useful. Today, it is hard to answer and view questions that concern concrete positions.

Comment: I think this is a very important feature. Let's up-vote it more and perhaps it will be implemented!

Comment: It's 2020 now and this is still an unsolved problem. I don't have the time for yet another project, but where could potential developers get hands on the code? Maybe think about GSC mentoring...

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can open the post in the browser (it's an option in the More link in the Android app and the Share link in the iOS app),

[image]
[image]

and (if necessary) scroll down to the bottom to switch from the mobile theme to the new responsive design, by clicking the 'full site' link in the footer.

[image]
[image]