# Integrating a live Chess board

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When I visited the chess section I am only seeing the **PGN & FEN**. To analyze the game properly I have to copy the PGN's and paste it into Lichess.org to visualize the board. The process is very cumbersome and many people do not love this process.

Why people are not integrating a chess board inside the app for instant visualization and evaluation of the positions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Board in mobile app](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/board-in-mobile-app)

Comment: That said, [mobile app development is frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/241919).